# Need help sorting a list by numbers and names

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to sort some items in a list by name a-z/z-a and or price low/high by using a dropdown option. 
The price uses a < h1 > and the name uses a < class ="item" > tag.

I've looked around but it looks like not many people use a drop down < option > menu. 
I'm not strong in JS...but I'd love to learn from you all!

```js
function price() {
  document.getElementById("list");
  
}

function name() {
  document.getElementById("list");
  
}
```

```html
<div id="sort">
<p>Sort by</p>
<select>
<optgroup label= "Price"/>
<option value="low" onclick="price()">Price - Low </option>
<option value="high" onclick="price()">Price - High </option>
<optgroup label= "Name"/>
<option value="name"onclick="Name()">Name A - Z</option>
<option value="nameRev" onclick="name()">Name Z - A</option>
</select>
</div>


<ul>
<li><h1>$1 </h1><h2 class="item">B </h2></li>
<li><h1>$7 </h1><h2 class="item">A </h2></li>
<li><h1>$8 </h1><h2 class="item"> H</h2></li>
<li><h1>$11 </h1><h2 class="item">F</h2></li>
<li><h1>$5 </h1><h2 class="item">N </h2></li>
<li><h1>$7</h1><h2 class="item">M </h2></li>
<li><h1>$6</h1><h2 class="item">C </h2></li>
<li><h1>$9 </h1><h2 class="item">G </h2></li>
<li><h1>$4</h1><h2 class="item">I </h2></li>
<li><h1>$10</h1><h2 class="item">D </h2></li>
<li><h1>$5</h1><h2 class="item"> J</h2></li>
<li><h1>$2 </h1><h2 class="item">E </h2></li>
<li><h1>$3</h1><h2 class="item">K </h2></li>
<li><h1>$1.1 </h1><h2 class="item">L </h2></li>

<li><h1>$12 </h1><h2 class="item">ZB </h2></li>
<li><h1>$34 </h1><h2 class="item">AA </h2></li>
<li><h1>$56 </h1><h2 class="item"> VH</h2></li>
<li><h1>$74 </h1><h2 class="item">BF</h2></li>
<li><h1>$865 </h1><h2 class="item">BN </h2></li>
<li><h1>$35</h1><h2 class="item">CM </h2></li>
<li><h1>$87</h1><h2 class="item">CC </h2></li>
<li><h1>$65 </h1><h2 class="item">FG </h2></li>
<li><h1>$45</h1><h2 class="item">YI </h2></li>
<li><h1>$53</h1><h2 class="item">WD </h2></li>
<li><h1>$64</h1><h2 class="item"> KJ</h2></li>
<li><h1>$53</h1><h2 class="item">QE </h2></li>
<li><h1>$74</h1><h2 class="item">QK </h2></li>
<li><h1>$72 </h1><h2 class="item">YL </h2></li>
</ul>
```

Here's what I've got:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function price(direction) {
  // const direction = e.target.value
  // console.log(value)
  // console.log(direction)
  const ul = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0]

  // get the only ul
  let items = ul.innerHTML

  // split string lines to arr of items and only include valid items
  items = items.split('</h2></li>').filter(item => item.includes('$'))

  items = items.map(item => {
    // console.log(item)
    item = item.split('$')[1]
    const [strPrice, otherString] = item.split('</h1>')
    const price = parseFloat(strPrice)
    const name = otherString.split('<h2 class="item">')[1]
    return { price, name }
  })
  
  // console.log(items) // check the new arr of items

  // sort by comparing the float values of item.price
  direction === 'low' ?
  items = items.sort((a, b) => a.price > b.price) :
  items = items.sort((a, b) => a.price < b.price)
  // console.log(items)

  // clear the ul so that you can re-populate it
  ul.innerHTML = ''

  // append each (ordered) item to the ul
  items.forEach(item => {
    li = document.createElement('li')
    li.innerHTML = `<li><h1>$${item.price}</h1><h2 class="item">${item.name}</h2></li>`
    ul.appendChild(li)
  })

}

function name() {
  document.getElementById("list");
  
}
```

```html
<div id="sort">
<p>Sort by</p>
<select>
<optgroup label= "Price"/>
<option value="low" onclick="price('low')">Price - Low </option>
<option value="high" onclick="price('high')">Price - High </option>
<optgroup label= "Name"/>
<option value="name"onclick="Name()">Name A - Z</option>
<option value="nameRev" onclick="name()">Name Z - A</option>
</select>
</div>


<ul>
<li><h1>$1 </h1><h2 class="item">B </h2></li>
<li><h1>$7 </h1><h2 class="item">A </h2></li>
<li><h1>$8 </h1><h2 class="item"> H</h2></li>
<li><h1>$11 </h1><h2 class="item">F</h2></li>
<li><h1>$5 </h1><h2 class="item">N </h2></li>
<li><h1>$7</h1><h2 class="item">M </h2></li>
<li><h1>$6</h1><h2 class="item">C </h2></li>
<li><h1>$9 </h1><h2 class="item">G </h2></li>
<li><h1>$4</h1><h2 class="item">I </h2></li>
<li><h1>$10</h1><h2 class="item">D </h2></li>
<li><h1>$5</h1><h2 class="item"> J</h2></li>
<li><h1>$2 </h1><h2 class="item">E </h2></li>
<li><h1>$3</h1><h2 class="item">K </h2></li>
<li><h1>$1.1 </h1><h2 class="item">L </h2></li>

<li><h1>$12 </h1><h2 class="item">ZB </h2></li>
<li><h1>$34 </h1><h2 class="item">AA </h2></li>
<li><h1>$56 </h1><h2 class="item"> VH</h2></li>
<li><h1>$74 </h1><h2 class="item">BF</h2></li>
<li><h1>$865 </h1><h2 class="item">BN </h2></li>
<li><h1>$35</h1><h2 class="item">CM </h2></li>
<li><h1>$87</h1><h2 class="item">CC </h2></li>
<li><h1>$65 </h1><h2 class="item">FG </h2></li>
<li><h1>$45</h1><h2 class="item">YI </h2></li>
<li><h1>$53</h1><h2 class="item">WD </h2></li>
<li><h1>$64</h1><h2 class="item"> KJ</h2></li>
<li><h1>$53</h1><h2 class="item">QE </h2></li>
<li><h1>$74</h1><h2 class="item">QK </h2></li>
<li><h1>$72 </h1><h2 class="item">YL </h2></li>
</ul>
```

Here is an example for manipulating the DOM to achieve the results for "price-sorting".

You can do this a bunch of ways and my answer is similar to [Aleksandar Grbic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3656274/aleksandar-grbic)'s but I scrape the DOM to create an array of 'item' objects.

Also, notice that the price function is called with an argument to determine the direction of the sorting.

Key areas to review: (MDN is a great first resource for answering your own questions) the [String.split() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), [Array methods (filter, map, forEach)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), and general [DOM manipulation](https://www.sitepoint.com/dom-manipulation-vanilla-javascript-no-jquery/) (I just used the first link that seemed helpful).

I tried to make the flow of the function easy to follow and included the useful console logs for checking that my values where what I wanted/expected.

If you have follow-up questions on the price function I'd be happy to answer them, I'll leave the name sorting for you.

Good luck, js is pretty rad so stick with tinkering with it + there are a TON of great resources (a great intro is [FreeCodeCamp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/)).

Answer (score 1):

You should store the list of those items in an array and append them dynamically. This will give you ability to operate on a data type rather then hardcoded values in your document.

After you do so, you can use a native [Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method to achieve what you wanted. Also, the reason why you got down-voted is due to your very general question. Either be more specific or spend more time learning the necessary technologies to achieve what you want.